# Read all the csv files in path as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv

I want to read all the `csv` files in my `input_path` as a dataframe `df`. My code raises `NameError: name 'df' is not defined` error.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

input_path = "../samples/input_data/"

# Open all the subfolders within path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:
            df = pd.read_csv(data)

print(df)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2834/400103009.py in <module>
----> 1 print(df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: The directories you're looking at are empty, so the loops never run

Comment: Better use an absolute path instead of a relative one because the latter may not point to where you expect it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

input_path = "../samples/input_data/"

# Open all the subfolders within path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:
            df = pd.read_csv(data)
            print(df)
```

I think this should work. When you come out of for loop python doesnt know what df is . So if want to print df or do some other actions then do it within the for loop itself.
You can also use a function.

Comment: That simply isn't true. Loops don't have scope. Your approach _would_ fix the error, but by the wrong reasoning

Comment: That may be true. But then we have to define df before the for loop. Then the last file read will be printed

Comment: It doesn't print anything

Comment: No, that's not true again. You're still talking as though loops have scope. _They don't_. If you defined `df` before the loops, you'd get an empty dataframe printed at the end because this code doesn't read a single file

Comment: I think their is no need for this "with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:"

Comment: Then you think incorrectly. There are no files for them to open, but removing that code would be a mistake. I don't think you have an understanding of this problem at all. Not understanding the code is fine, except that you've posted an answer that the OP has then run and not got the output they expected, so everyone is getting more confused